# Correct way to link with /usr/lib/libgtest_main.a?

Tags: c++, gcc, googletest

I got `libgtest-dev` installed and it brought me `/usr/lib/libgtest_main.a` and `/usr/lib/libgtest.a`.

Now I am trying to link a simple test application. The following command produces me a functional executable:

```
g++ -pthread sample1.o sample1_unittest.o /usr/lib/libgtest.a /usr/lib/libgtest_main.a
```

Is there a way to instruct the linker to search for `.a` files? Is there a way to assemble the application in one step (compile and link)?

Comment: Read the [linker options documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options), I'm sure you could find an option to link *statically*.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg with `-static` flag it produces a warning (Using 'getaddrinfo' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking) and creates oversized binary. Or did you mean some other option?

Comment: No that was it. There might be other options to tell the linker to link only specific libraries static, I don't know about that. You might have to read the [`ld` documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/) for that.